# ble scanning working on android 11, android 7 but not on android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have given all the permission for BLE but it's not working in android 10. I think this is related to permissions or SDK but I have given all of them but still, it not working in android 10 and working fine in android 11 and android 7

```
 compileSdk 30
 defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.bledevice.g"
            minSdk 29
            targetSdk 30
    }
```

I have given all the permissions:

```
    void refresh() {
            requestPermission(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
    
            }, 100);
        }
```

androidmainfest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <!--Used to write cached data to the expansion memory card-->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean when you say "not working". And at least show the code used to start the actual scanning. Also does it work in another app like nRF Connect?

Comment: Do you have the location service enabled in your android 10 device? BLE scanner requires the location service in order to locate exactly the devices around.